# Laravel Eloquent Relationship AVG having

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have `store` table related to `product` table, that have `product.rating` (int) 1 to 5

I want to find store that have average product rating 3 star or any based on my post data

My code

```
$store = new Store;
if ((int)$request->input('store-rating')>0) {
    $store->whereHas('product',function($query) use($request) {
        $rate = $request->input('product-rating');
        $query->where(DB::raw('AVG(rating)'),$rate);
    });
}
$store->with('product');
$thestore = $store->paginate(6);

return $thestore;
```

its always return all data like its ignore my POST `store-rating` value

Here is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as AuthUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\ModelBuilder;

class Store extends AuthUser
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }


}
```

---

**Solution**

as answered below I should be using `groupBy` and `havingRaw` to make the query work, but it turn out that is not my only problem in the code

I changed the code to:

```
$store = Store::with('session');
if ((int)$request->input('store-rating')>0) {
    $store->whereHas('product',function($query) use($request) {
        $rate = $request->input('product-rating');
        $query->groupBy('rating')->havingRaw('AVG(rating) = '.$rate);
    });
}
$thestore = $store->paginate(6);

return $thestore;
```

its seem I cannot use `$store = new Store;` to start my model query

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `havingRaw`

```
$query->grouBy('rating')->havingRaw('AVG(rating) = '.$rate);
```

don't forget the group by